# Neo4j using UNWIND with MATCH performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to create an UNWIND query to parse a list. The MATCH query is running for each row in our list. Is there a way to make the MATCH query run only once and use the value for each row thereafter? We tried DISTINCT but failed.

```
UNWIND ${PACBatch} AS row
MATCH (e:Business {serial_number: row.ownerID})
CREATE (p:Person {serial_number: row.tempSerial, created: 
row.rowCreated})
CREATE (e)-[r:SELLS_ITEM {created: row.rowUpdated}]->(p)
RETURN p AS PER, r AS OWNS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you had in mind?

It assumes that you have a single business. If the business varies per row it would be trickier to cook something up.

```
// match the business node
MATCH (e:Business {serial_number: a_particular_ownerID })
WITH e

// then bring the business node forward and process each row in the UNWIND
UNWIND ${PACBatch} AS row
CREATE (p:Person {serial_number: row.tempSerial, created: row.rowCreated})
CREATE (e)-[r:SELLS_ITEM {created: row.rowUpdated}]->(p)
RETURN p AS PER, r AS OWNS
```